# Can I load Alex Voice in the Swift Playground

Tags: ios, swift, speech-synthesis, avspeechsynthesizer

I'm experimenting with Apple's speech synthesis, and I want to see how the Alex voice would sound on an iOS device.

Is there a way to make the Alex voice accessible via the Swift playground?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it will work if you add these two lines.

```
import PlaygroundSupport
PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
```

Since the voice synthesizer is asynchronous code, the "needsIndefiniteExecution" allows execution to continue after the end of the playground’s top-level code is reached. This, in turn, gives threads and callbacks time to execute. ([from Apple's documentation of Playground Support](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/playgroundsupport/playgroundpage/1964501-needsindefiniteexecution))

Example:

```
import AVFoundation
import PlaygroundSupport

PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
let synth  = AVSpeechSynthesizer()
let speech = AVSpeechUtterance(string: "Hello, World!")
speech.voice = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice(language: "en-US")
synth.speak(speech)
```

Comment: The example you linked to will use the 'Samantha' speech synthesizer voice; iOS has an an optional "Alex" voice (see here: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203077 ) which is an extra download on your phone/tablet; but as far as I can tell, it's unaccessible from the playground.

Comment: Oh, I believe you are right. The should provide the complete list and Alex does not appear to be there. print(AVSpeechSynthesisVoice.speechVoices())